# Android Studio Emulator unable to implement eglSurfaceAttrib

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Thanks in advance for any help.  I'm just starting to wade back into Android Dev and the new Android Studio is not playing nicely.  Here's what I have...

I'm running the most current version of **Android Studio on Ubuntu 14.04**.  Everything is up to date.  I did run into the **32 bit** vs **64 bit** issue but got that ironed out.  I'm finding that every app, even ones that do not generate new activities are not able to start in the emulator, even though the same app works fine on my Android phone over USB, and the code itself throws no errors.  This is even true of apps that worked perfectly well on the emulator just last week.  Below is the specific error I am getting.

```
W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented

W/OpenGLRender: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xe0d8c00, error=EGL_SUCCESS
```

This is repeated twice and then everything comes to a halt.  I've been through the studio settings but cannot find anything that could be causing this.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Extended discussion in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28966496/android-studio-emulator-eglsurfaceattrib-not-implemented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone stumbling upon this... I just switched to the genymotion emulator.  Worked out of the box.  Problem solved.